# Will a rectifier based on air gap and flexible foil work?

Tags: electrical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis

[image]
[image]

The white line is a flexible conducting foil suspended on the metal wire. I think the external DC circuit will induce a charge on the flexible part and the other charges move to ground. The charged flexible part will incline towards the oppositely charged electrode from the AC circuit and once the voltage reaches peak, the air breaks down and the charge is transferred. When the current switches, the flexible part moves towards the other electrode and a spark transfers the charge in the same direction as before.

Am I hideously mistaken?

Comment: the circuit portion on the left has no electrical path back to the rest of the circuit ... as it stands, it is just a plate in a capacitor, without outside connection

Comment: @jsotola check the edit.

Comment: how is the circuit disconnecting from the ground on one side, and then reconnecting to ground on the other side?

Comment: @jsotola Um, it's actually the same kind of "switch" :) Basically there's another switch circuit with a flexible conductor that has an induced positive charge, so it always moves toward the negative electrode on the left.